# $(X, \circ)$ is a group, define $a\circ b$

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $X$ be $\{1,2,3\}$ and $\circ$ a binary operation *over* $X$ such that $(X,\circ)$ forms a group, and $3\circ 3 = 3$.

Define $a\circ b$ for all $ a,b \in X$.

I think that the identity element is 3. But I am not sure how to proceed.

Comment: In this post you have referred separately to $X$, $\circ$, and $(X, \circ)$ as relations.  What do you mean by "relation"??  And since I think it is highly unlikely you actually mean "relation", what is $(X, \circ)$ in actuality?  A group?

Comment: $3\circ 3=3$ means $\circ$ is not a relation, it's a function.  A relation has a value of $\mathrm{true}$ or $\mathrm{false}$.

Comment: "linkage"???  It would seem you are making up terms here.  Try "binary operation".

Comment: i dont know. in german is verknüpfung

Comment: a 'verknüfung' o: X x X-->X @ goos

Comment: @d.i... Yeah, we call it "binary operation".  Thanks for being patient with us with the language barrier.

Comment: $X\circ X \to X$ is a binary operation.  If $3$ is the identity element then $a\circ 3= 3\circ a = a$ for all $a\in X$

Answer (score 3):

**Hints**

- $3 \circ 3 = 3 \implies 3 \circ 3 \circ 3^{-1} = 3 \circ 3^{-1}
  \implies 3 = e$, where $e$  is the identity element / neutral element.
- Remember that the multiplication table is like a sudoku board--every row and column has one of every number $1, 2, 3$.
  $$
  \begin{array}{|c|ccc|}
  \hline
  \circ & 1 & 2 & 3 \\
  \hline
  1 &  &  & 1 \\
  2 &  &  & 2 \\
  3 & 1 & 2 & 3 \\
  \hline
  \end{array}
  $$
- If $1 \circ 2 = 2$ or $1 \circ 2 = 1$, then $1 = e$ or $2 = e$, which cannot be true.  So $1 \circ 2 = 3$.  Similarly, what is $2 \circ 1$?

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to assume that you mean $(X,\circ)$ forms a *group*.

With this assumption, we know that $(X,\circ)$ is a group of order three. However, every group of order three is isomorphic to $(\Bbb Z/3\Bbb Z,+)$ (can you prove this?). The Cayley table for $(\Bbb Z/3\Bbb Z,+)$ is
$$
\begin{array}{c|ccc}
+  & 0 & 1 & 2 \\ \hline
0 & 0 & 1 & 2 \\
1 & 1 & 2 & 0 \\
2 & 2 & 0 & 1
\end{array}
$$
Note that in this Cayley table, the only element $a$ of $\Bbb Z/3\Bbb Z$ that satisfies $a^2=a$ is $a=0$. Thus $3$ is the identity element of $(X,\circ)$, allowing us to fill in part of the Cayley table for $(X,\circ)$:
$$
\begin{array}{c|ccc}
\circ  & 3 & 2 & 1 \\ \hline
3 & 3 & 2 & 1 \\
2 & 2 & ? & ? \\
1 & 1 & ? & ?
\end{array}
$$

Next, note that non-identity elements $a$ in $\Bbb Z/3\Bbb Z$ satisfy $a^2\neq 0$ and $a^2\neq a$. This gives us two more spots in the Cayley table:
$$
\begin{array}{c|ccc}
\circ  & 3 & 2 & 1 \\ \hline
3 & 3 & 2 & 1 \\
2 & 2 & 1 & ? \\
1 & 1 & ? & 2
\end{array}
$$

Finally, note that the two non-identity elements in $\Bbb Z/3\Bbb Z$ are inverses of each other. This completes the Cayley table:
$$
\begin{array}{c|ccc}
\circ  & 3 & 2 & 1 \\ \hline
3 & 3 & 2 & 1 \\
2 & 2 & 1 & 3 \\
1 & 1 & 3 & 2
\end{array}
$$

If you're having trouble proving that every group of order three is isomorphic to $\Bbb Z/3\Bbb Z$, then you can still fill in the Cayley table using @Goos's method.

Comment: thank you @ goos @ brian fitzpatrick

Answer (score 0):

Knowing only $3\circ 3=3$, we start with the table: $$\begin{array}{c|ccc}\circ & 1 & 2 & 3 \\ \hline 1 & & & \\ 2 & & & \\ 3 & & & 3\end{array}$$

By definition, a **group** is *closed, associative, has a unique identity element, and every element has an unique inverse*.

**Closed:** $\forall a,b\in X \implies a\circ b \in X$.  Thus the only image of the operator are within the group, $X$.

**Associative:** $(a\circ b)\circ c = a\circ (b\circ c)$

**Identity:** $\forall a\in X: a\circ e = e\circ a = a$.  NB: since $3\circ 3 = 3$ then $3$ is the identity element.

**Inverse:** $\forall a\in X, \exists a^{-1}\in X: a\circ a^{-1} = a^{-1}\circ a = 3$.  The inverse is unique for each element.

---

Thus we can fill in some more of the graph from the existence of the identity:

$$\begin{array}{c|ccc}\circ & 1 & 2 & 3 \\ \hline 1 & & & 1 \\ 2 & & & 2 \\ 3 & 1 & 2 & 3\end{array}$$

Since the identity is unique $1\circ 1\neq 1$, $2\circ 2 \neq 2$, $1\circ 2\neq 1\neq 2\circ 1$,  $1\circ 2\neq 1\neq 2\circ 1$.  This lets us fill in two more squares.

$$\begin{array}{c|ccc}\circ & 1 & 2 & 3 \\ \hline 1 & & 3 & 1 \\ 2 &3 & & 2 \\ 3 & 1 & 2 & 3\end{array}$$

Noting that these give us the inverse for $1$ and $2$, and since the inverse is unique for each element, then this lets us fill in the final squares:

$$\begin{array}{c|ccc}\circ & 1 & 2 & 3 \\ \hline 1 & 2 & 3 & 1 \\ 2 &3 & 1 & 2 \\ 3 & 1 & 2 & 3\end{array}$$

All that remains to do is check that this table is associative.

Comment: Pft!  Fast typists beat me too it.  But we all appear to have arrived at the same solution by approximately the same reasoning.